# Cacti not working for SNMP data sources

Tags: debian, monitoring, snmp, cacti, snmpd

I installed packages `cacti` and `snmpd` on a Debian server. I'm able to display common graphs in Cacti (such as memory usage, load average, logged in users, etc) using the data templates listed as *Unix*. Now I want to replace these graphs with new ones using *SNMP* data sources, because I see there is also *CPU usage* and because it's not excluded I have to manage multiple hosts in the future.

So, I installed `snmpd` on the machine and left the `snmpd.conf` as it is. In Cacti, I created three new data sources from *SNMP* templates for *127.0.0.1* host:

- ucd/net - CPU Usage - Nice
- ucd/net - CPU Usage - System
- ucd/net - CPU Usage - User

Then I created a new graph from template *ucd/net - CPU Usage*, and select the three data sources in the *Graph Item Fields* section. Graph is now **enabled and running, but empty**. No data have been collected.

Under *Console -> Devices* my *SNMP* host is listed as up and running:

```
System:Linux ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx 3.2.0-23-virtual #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:29:03 UTC 2012 x86_64
Uptime: 929267 (0 days, 2 hours, 34 minutes)
Hostname: ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx
Location: Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
Contact: Me me@example.org
```

In *SNMP Options* I left all as it is:

- SNMP Version: Version 1
- SNMP Community: public
- SNMP Timeout: 500 ms
- Maximum OID's Per Get Request: 10

In *Console -> Utilities -> Cacti Log* I have multiple warning (two for each data source) every 5 minutes:

```
10/29/2012 01:45:01 PM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] Host[2] DS[18] WARNING: Result from SNMP not valid. Partial Result: U
10/29/2012 01:45:01 PM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] WARNING: SNMP Get Timeout for Host:'127.0.0.1', and OID:'.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0'
10/29/2012 01:45:01 PM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] Host[1] DS[9] WARNING: Result from SNMP not valid. Partial Result: U
10/29/2012 01:45:01 PM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] WARNING: SNMP Get Timeout for Host:'127.0.0.1', and OID:'.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52.0'
10/29/2012 01:40:01 PM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] Host[2] DS[19] WARNING: Result from SNMP not valid. Partial Result: U
10/29/2012 01:40:01 PM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] WARNING: SNMP Get Timeout for Host:'127.0.0.1', and OID:'.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0' 
[...]
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something, but I cannot get it...

Comment: cat /etc/snmp/snmp.conf will give you serious hint. Also consider typing  snmpwalk -Cc -On -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU `snmp.conf` is empty and says I have no MIB files; I'm not sure about what they are and if I need them... The output of the command you suggested me is **[here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JbCSumtJ)**.

Comment: MIB files are comfortable as they help translating numeric oids to text. It seems ucd snmp has been revomed from debian in 2006.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this command (*OID* is from Cacti log):

SNMPv1:

```
  $ snmpwalk -Cc -On -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52.0
```

SNMPv2c: Nowadays is very common SNMPv2c as default, so also try.

```
  $ snmpwalk -Cc -On -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52.0
```

Also, try changing COMMUNITY and/or IP ADDRESS to local network instead loopback.

If you don't get a result like `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52.0 = Counter32: 250038`, then edit  `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` adding or decommenting:

```
rocommunity public  localhost
```

And restart `snmpd` using one of:

```
/etc/init.d/snmpd restart
service snmpd restart
```

Comment: The `snmpwalk` command returned `End of MIB` only. I edit `snmpd.conf` as you suggested, and now I get `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52.0 = Counter32: 0`. Cool. Now I'm waiting for Cacti to see if something changes. In the meantime I'm trying to figure out what of the configuration lines you posted did the job.

Comment: Ok, I edited your answer removing non-needed parts. Thank you, now it works!

Comment: Just succeeded in getting things works also for remote hosts! I just needed to remove local binding from `agentAddress` and specify an IP/Netmask in `rocommunity` definition instead of `localhost` (in the SNMPd.conf of these remote machines). Now Cacti is monitoring all my network! Thank you very much Eric!